# How to decompose this polynomial?!

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I will be really grateful if you could help me out here with decomposing this polynomial.

Decompose:

$x^{5k}+x^k+1$

This might be a child's play but well,I'm stuck a little bit.

P.S:edit the tags please if you feel not right about them.Thanks

Comment: If $3\nmid k, (x^2+x+1)\mid(x^{5k}+x^k+1)$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee what if $k=3t$?

Comment: You can solve this partially using primitve roots.

Comment: could you give more explanation please? @JefLaga

Comment: no help? any one?

Comment: Is this an actual school question or what? The roots factorization of $y^5+y+1$ (when setting $y = x^k$) is some involved complex crap, just ask Wolfram Alpha about it.

Comment: so I guess I've written the question wrong after all,but this is what I'm seeing on this bleeding paper!

Comment: You could make use of $(x^{5k}+x^k+1) = (x^{2k}+x^k+1)(-x^{2k}+x^{3k}+1)$

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align*}x^{5k}+x^k+1&=x^{5k}-x^{2k}+(x^{2k}+x^k+1)\\
&=x^{2k}(x^k-1)(x^{2k}+x^k+1)+(x^{2k}+x^k+1)\\
&=(x^{2k}+x^k+1)(x^{3k}-x^{2k}+1)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to *factor* the polynomial (that is, write it as a *product* of simpler polynomials), or to *decompose* it (that is, write it as a *functional composition* of simpler polynomials)?

Factoring is the more common of the operations, and ordinarily one would suspect this was what you meant (and that some kind of language barrier led you to write "decompose" instead). However, this particular polynomial seems to be tailor-made to being actually *decomposed* because obviously
$$ (x\mapsto x^{5k}+x^k+1) = (x\mapsto x^5+x+1)\circ(x\mapsto x^k) $$

The left composant can't be further decomposed (except trivially with linear polynomials, which are uninteresting because they are invertible). The degree of a composition of polynomials is always the product of the degrees, and 5 is prime.

Whether $x^k$ can be decomposed depends on the prime factorization of $k$. There would be one composant of $(x\mapsto x^p)$ for each prime factor of $k$, with multiplicity.

Comment: +1 It's easy to factor this expression if you first try to simplify it by making a substitution, specifically $t=x^k$.

Then
$$x^{5k}+x^k+1$$
becomes
$$t^5+t+1$$
Now for the hint
$$\begin{array}{lll}
t^5+t+1 &=& t^5+t^4+t^3+t^2+t+1 - (t^4+t^3+t^2)\\
&=& (t^5+t^4+t^3)+(t^2+t+1) - (t^4+t^3+t^2)\\
&=& \dots
\end{array}$$

Keep in mind though that if your professor wanted you to factor this expression, he/she would have said "factor". For this reason, I think that he/she likely meant "functional decomposition".

Answer (score 0):

Set $y=x^k$.

Then, as pointed by others, $$y^5+y+1=(y^2+y+1)(y^3-y^2+1).$$

You will find the (complex) roots of the first factor easily. You will find the (real+complex pair) roots of the second factor less easily, but there are closed formulas (ask Wolfram).

Eventually, get the $x$ roots from $x=\sqrt[k]y$ (using the $k^{th}$ roots of unit) and write down the complete factorization.